# Using `modulo` how to get 3 columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, underscore.js, modulo

I am trying to split my data in to 3 colusing using this tempalte:

```
<% _.each(userDetails.userFunctionMaps, function(item, index){ %>
                    <% if(item.function.reference.toUpperCase() == "PCOPERF") %>
                <tr>
                    <% if( index  % 3 == 0) %>
                    <td><%= item.function.functionName %></td>
                    <td> :<%=  item.function.active == "Y" ? "Y" : "N" %></td>
                    <% if(index  % 3 == 1) %>
                    <td><%= item.function.functionName %></td>
                    <td> :<%=  item.function.active == "Y" ? "Y" : "N" %></td>
                    <% if(index  % 3 == 2) %>
                        <td> <%= item.function.functionName %></td>
                        <td> :<%=  item.function.active == "Y" ? "Y" : "N" %></td>
                </tr>

                <% })%>
```

But the `modulo` is not retuning the corect out put..

Any one help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my template like this, it works fine:

```
<table>
            <tbody>
                <% _.each(userDetails.userFunctionMaps, function(item, index){ %>



                    <% if(item.function.reference.toUpperCase() == "PCOPERF") %>

                    <% if(index % 3 == 0) { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td>

                            <%= index %><%= item.function.functionName %>

                        </td>
                        <td> :<%=  item.function.active == "Y" ? "Y" : "N" %></td>
                        <% } %>

                        <% if(index % 3 == 1) { %>
                        <td>

                            <%= index %><%= item.function.functionName %>

                        </td>
                        <td> :<%=  item.function.active == "Y" ? "Y" : "N" %></td>
                        <% } %>
                        <% if(index % 3 == 2) { %>
                        <td>

                            <%= index %><%= item.function.functionName %>

                        </td>
                        <td> :<%=  item.function.active == "Y" ? "Y" : "N" %></td>
                      </tr>
                    <% } %>

                <% })%>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Thanks to all.